# Storage HDD migration without losing shared folders (Rpi & OMV)

Tags: linux, raid, symbolic-link

Right now I have a 1TB HDD plugged in my Raspberry Pi using a SATA-USB case.
I plan on buying the https://wiki.geekworm.com/NASPi_Gemini_3.5 which is :
an enclosure for two 3.5" HDD
RAID support
secure shutdown with a button
fan speed control depending on CPU's temperature (works with a bash script)

I asked the support via email if it is possible to plug a 2.5" HDD on the board, they answered yes ; so I can still use my 1TB HDD. Now, this happened a few times during setup a year ago : if I start the Raspberry Pi without the HDD (where I only have shared folders for storage), the OMV web GUI fails to load, and I was solving that last year by clean installing OMV (if I recall, but I guess now with a bit more experience that editing fstab and rebotting might have been sufficient). So, my first question is : if I unplug the HDD and attach it to the GeekWorm board :
do the partitions' UUID change ?
am I sure the RPi will detect the HDD at startup and not crash OMV ?
If I'm buying this dual-HDD board, that's because I plan on adding more storage...
Say I buy a 4TB HDD.
Now, my 1TB HDD is divided in 4 partitions :
Shares (29 GB)
General Storage (210GB)
Backups (300GB)
Media (380GB)

Basically, I have symbolic links on the OS SDcard pointing folders on the external HDD. These symlinks are what are treated as shared folders by OMV for the sftp plugin.
On Windows in the Disk Manager you can create a spanned partition, which means a partition on both drives. Is there an equivalent for Linux ?
I know you might answer RAID 0, but striping a file isn't what I'm talking about : I don't want a file to be separated, but rather both disks to be counted as one of 5TB and be able to create partitions on  it as if it was one disk. But I still want one file to be stored on one single physical drive. Is that possible ? So if 1 HDD goes, I lose the files that were physically on it, but the files on the other are OK.

Thanks for your help !